# Eclipse auto delete apk after install apk

Tags: android

my system will open the installation if user click on the button

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://sdcard/abc.apk"), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

i am looking for the solution which the system will auto delete the apk file once the installation is done.

Comment: Use ant or maven to script it

Comment: @melvintcs: did you find the solution to delete apk after installed?

Answer (score 1):

You could listen from the intent broadcast ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED. [Here is a list of all intent broadcasts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Do note that there are different broadcasts if the package is installed, or if it updates another package. I would guess that there are information in the broadcast as to which package that was installed, so you don't accidentally delete the apk when another app is installed :)

Comment: can u provide with more example? i rarely get the information from google

Comment: It is just listening to a broadcast. You should be able to find several examples on google and stackoverflow.

Comment: @pgsandstrom form the docs: Note that the newly installed package does not receive this broadcast.